# MDX Calculated Member filter using attribute not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have this setup:

```
ID  T   Date
2   T2  2022-11-18
3   T1  2022-11-21
```

and in the main fact table there are deals with ID 2 and 3.

Date is an attribute and appears, and works correctly, as a slicer in a pivot table in Excel. T is also an attribute, not visible, purely for the calculated members.

I created a Calculated Member and it doesn't work:

```
([Date].[T].&[T2], [Measures].[Notional_SUM])
```

However a check/test using ID does:

```
([Date].[ID].&[2], [Measures].[Notional_SUM])
```

obviously this works as 2 is actually in the fact table but what have I forgotten such that using T does not work?

I want to be able to use T as there'll always be T1 and T2 dates but I may not always know the ID (auto- generated by the SQL script rolling the dates).

***EDIT - After testing in Excel I realised that the one I thought does not work actually does if Date is removed from the slicer/top setup.

So obviously the top/slicer is a WHERE on just that date meaning my calculated member

```
([Date].[T].&[T2], [Measures].[Notional_SUM])
```

does not 'find' any T2 in the data it sees.

So how can I have a Calculated Member that always shows the T2 data?

I'm constructing an SSAS copy of an existing in-memory Java OLAP cube which does this and I have to ensure all dims/measures are the same.

Thanks

Leigh
tilleytech.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually as I've not used SSAS before I'm still learning bits and I had not checked out the attribute relationship tab.

I used the attribute relationship tab to define that T is related to Date and not ID (the ID links to the fact tables).

Once this was done the behaviour now works and when Date is changed the T2 values, and move/diff calculated members, all work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

it has been long long time since I wrote MDX, and as I do not have a running SSAS to debug your issue, I will try to dig the answer from my memory.

There is a difference between the use of &, which I believe is to be used on keys, and not on members. Try to use this:

```
([Date].[T].[T2], [Measures].[Notional_SUM])
```

Comment: Thanks. as I'd been learning as I went along I didn't realise & is for use with keys. It still didn't work though...well, it shows values when the Date for T2 is in scope, but I want it to always show the T2 value even alongside the T1 date. I've aske the question on a Microsoft SSAS forum too where there are experts so I'm hoping they'll answer me soon as they've asked for what I am trying to achieve. It's basically a 'query' into the other co-ordinate/location to retrieve the T2 value

Comment: Your suggestion is pointing out on a lack basic understanding of a multidimensional cube. 

Each cell in the multidimensional cube has a value on each of the dimension, even when you do not specify it. The default member of each dimension is is use when none is specified. Unles changed the default member of all dimensions is the All Members level.

Comment: So if you want to show the values of T2 even when T1 is in context, you need to do it in some stages in the calculation. 

Start with using the all members level and see how you can make a measure that shows the total across all time levels , then you use this to slice it by the T1.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I think I confused you/made it seem like i do not understand by using the word 'query' which I'd only used as inside the Java in-memory cube I work on there are leaflevel calculators that do actually perform queries sometimes to retrieve arguments/components of a larger calculation. Anyway, see below I have it working now as I used the attribute relationship tab to alter how T is related to Date. :)